# Java process pegging CPU at 100%

Tags: java, windows, cpu-usage, taskmanager

We have an application which is running normally in a variety environments.   However, at one client site when the application invokes a child process (in this case CODEFIND.EXF - please see enclosed displayed) it pegs the processor at 100%.   I need help in interpreting the display.  Although the display seems to indicate that the parent process is consuming all the resources, could it in fact be due to the child process that the parent process invoked?   How could I tell this?

Thank you,

Elliott
[image]

Comment: so you got the client to you a screenshot?  Is there any way you could get your client (or have someone tech-savvy enough to get to the client site) to issue a "kill -3" (CTRL-\ under Windows IIRC) to get a full thread dump of your Java app?  Then you may find easily which thread is busy-looping (or something else) and where.  Another option which we used is to have the app respond to special commands and generate (and send to our server) automatically full thread dump on demand (you can then simply ask your client to, say, open the "About" menu and then issue a magic keystrokes etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The display indicates that the culprit is java.exe. That indication is correct. The child process is not consuming CPU.